# Reading from file: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python

Please note - this question has been asked before, but none of the responses answered the question satisfactorily.

Here is the code

```
    numberList = []
    for x in range(6):
        numberList.append(int(input("Enter a number: ")))

    myFile = open("challenge 37.txt", "wt") #The 'wt' meaning  the 't'ext is being 
    opened for 'w'riting.

    for nums in numberList:
        myFile.write(str(nums) + "\n")

    myFile.close()




    myFile = open("challenge 37.txt", "rt") #The 'rt' meaning the 't'ext is being 
    opened for 'r'eading.

    contents = myFile.read()
    contents = contents.strip("\n")

    print("The contents of the file are:\n" + str(contents))
    total = 0
    for nums in contents.strip("\n"):
        total = total + nums

    average = total / 6

    print("The total of your number is " + str(total) + ", and the average of those 
    numbers is " + str(average))


    myFile.close()
```

This program returns an error : (TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str')
This is for line number 25. Could anyone please shed light on the predicament? This is a homework.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you do not need to strip data but you need to split data using "\n" so you will get list of element and computation operation on list is easy.
solution for this :

```
contents = myFile.read()
contents = contents.split("\n")[:-1]                       #split data
print("The contents of the file are:\n" + str(contents))
total = 0
for nums in contents:                                     
    total = total + int(nums)
average = total / 6
print("The total of your number is " + str(total) + ", and the average of those numbers is " + str(average))
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply Maulik. :) It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Your content is read as string, so you should probably convert it to `int`:

```
total = total + int(nums)
```